# What is the best way to display a mouseover with an ellipsis showing the remaining text in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I'm tasked with creating a mouseover with an ellipsis that extends the missing characters from a field. I started looking at the api's and I narrowed it down to a popup panel or a dialog box. Which is better for this or is there another widget that would work better?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a mouseover (no clicking) then a popup would probably be a more better choice. Check out UIObject#setTitle()

Comment: Yes, it's just a mouseover. If the text field has more data than can be displayed, then the mouseover shows the remaining text.

Comment: Well I should have mentioned that it's for a cellList, so setTitle() will handle it with one line of code. Thanks!